# Spawn xterm and issue commands using Expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to write a GUI using Tcl/tk where the user will select different parameters and hit a 'Submit' button.  When the button is pressed, the program will open an xterm window and telnet and perform configurations based on the choices made by the user.  I know this should be pretty basic but I've looked everywhere and cannot find a working method.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: So.. Do you need help with Tk, with expect, or with spawning processes?  Got any working code examples?

Comment: I guess I need help with a combination of all 3.  I don't have any working code examples as I don't really know how to start as I'm still a beginner with Tcl/tk and Expect.  I just know that when I use 'spawn xterm' or 'exec xterm', the terminal will pop up but I can't issue any commands to it.  For example, I'd like the user to specify an IP address.  After the 'Submit' button is pressed, I want to open up an xterm and telnet to that IP address.

Comment: Telnet? Ugh! Can't you use ssh instead? (Telnet's a horrible historical artifact from before the advent of the need to secure everything properly.)

Answer (score 0):

I think xterm isn't needed: Expect is able to provide a program (telnet in your case) with a pseudoterminal -- one of the things xterm does for the program it's running.  So just [google for this combo](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=expect%20telnet).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was able to use spawn telnet to telnet into a server.  However, when I try to use the send command, it gives me "Error: wrong # args: should be "send ?options? interpName arg?arg...?"  Not sure why I'm getting this as it seems like I should be able to just use "send ___" to send commands.

Comment: but the command has to be in quotes, ending with a carriage return. example: `spawn bash; send "ls -l \r"`

Comment: Yeah I tried that.  Keeps giving me the error that the arguments are wrong, even when I have something like `send "hello\r"`

Comment: @user943251, judging from the `send`'s expected arguments, I can say it looks like the `send` command provided by Tk (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/send.htm). Are you using Expect as a package loaded into a regular Tcl program which also uses Tk (GUIs, that is)? If yes, you'll probably need to disambiguate the call using something like `expect::send` (but note I have zero experience with Expect so it's just a wild guess).

Comment: @kostix, you're probably thinking of `exp_send`

Comment: @user943251 can you post your expect code as part of your question so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: @glenn jackman, according to http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect yes, that's what I intended to propose. Moreover, I checked that `send` of Tk 8.4 does really refer to its first argument as `interpName` so probably the original poster does really use Tk.

Comment: @user943251, it worth mentioning that if you really use Expect from inside GUI app this could be a suboptimal solution as if the `send` or `expect` command will block due to network slowness/outage, then supposedly the GUI will freeze. Hence a more appropriate solution seems to be constructing a script for the Expect *binary* and spawning the Expect process using `open "| expect"` idiom, passing it the constructed script to stdin and reading its output via `fileevent` to ensure the GUI stays responsive all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Here's what my code looks like:  `#!/bin/sh  #\  exec wish "$0" "$@"  #  package require Expect  proc push_button {} {  spawn telnet <ip address>  expect "Password:"  exp_send "<password"  }`  After switching to exp_send, I no longer get the error I was talking about before.  However, it doesn't seem to work as it doesn't look like it's actually sending the commands.  Sorry I don't know how to format comments properly as the double-spacing for line breaks isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that expect can control an X app such as xterm. It can however control a text app like telnet.

You can write a shell script that launches xterm, passing the "-e" option to execute an expect script. That expect script can then launch telnet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Looking up examples online, I see that people use the send command after "spawn telnet <ip address>" and can successfully issue commands to the telnet (such as logging in with a username and password).  However, when I try it, I can telnet to the ip address I want, but for the send commands I get the error: "Error: wrong # args: should be "send ?options? interpName arg?arg...?"  Is there something wrong with the way I set it up?  Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to show us the exact send command you're using. Or, as hinted by kostix in a comment, use `exp_send`

Comment: Here's what my code looks like:  `#!/bin/sh  #\  exec wish "$0" "$@"  #  package require Expect  proc push_button {} {  spawn telnet <ip address>  expect "Password:"  exp_send "<password>"  }`  After switching to exp_send, I no longer get the error I was talking about before. However, it doesn't seem to work as it doesn't look like it's actually sending the commands. Sorry I don't know how to format comments properly as the double-spacing for line breaks isn't working

Comment: don't forget to "hit enter" after the password: `exp_send "password\r"`. For formatting, you should edit your question to add important information that may get lost in comments.

Comment: $glenn jackman Thanks.  After adding the \r at the end it's still not sending the password to the telnet.  When I execute the program, I see "Escape character is '^]'.


User Access Verification

Password: 
"but nothing else after that.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. It works perfectly now.  It turns out I needed '\n' at the end of the exp_send command, and with exp_internal I can monitor everything.  As a side question, how do I use expect to match just the last character?  For example, if the line I want to match may vary from server to server, but always ends with the same character, how would I do that?

Comment: probably best you ask in a separate question, with examples.